# How can display space in view blade laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

My records in db is like this :

[image]

I want to display with space

I try like this :

```
{{ nl2br($text) }}
```

and

```
{{ nl2br(e($text)) }}
```

It does not work

How can I solve it?

Comment: If no one can help me?

Comment: `{!! $text !!}` ?

Comment: @linktoahref, It's the same. It does not work

Comment: Normally HTML collapses multiple spaces into one. Have you checked the HTML *source* (and not what the browser renders) for spaces?

Answer (score 6):

have you tried using `{!! "&nbsp;" !!}`  here you can use HTML entity &nbsp

Answer (score 2):

you can create a helper like this
`$output = nl2br(str_replace(" ", " &nbsp;", $db_record));`

Then your blade file
{!! $output !!};

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
{!!nl2br($text)!!}
```

Comment: wow it works for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>` will put 4 spaces.

Another example

```
<p>{{'Hello'}}&nbsp;{{'World'}}
```

Will give you Hello World

Keyword `&nbsp;`

Answer (score -1):

This will provide space in laravel blade template.

```
{{ ' ' }}
```

Answer (score -2):

You Can use PHP bulid in funtion (&nbsp) for space